# Possibile to convert lat/long to country using HTML5 geolocation API under Manifest v2?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, geolocation, content-security-policy

I have a Google Chrome Extension which is running under Manifest v2. Previously, I was able to speak with http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp and be provided with the users country code (e.g. US, UK). However, Manifest v2 imposes restrictions which disallow speaking to non-https, whitelisted websites. This means I can't go out to a server for my information anymore.

I would like to continue to have this functionality. I believe my best bet is leveraging HTML5 geolocation to convert coordinates into country codes. I haven't seen any implementations of this  Is this possible to achieve within reason? All solutions I have found online propose communicating with a server and I have not come across an https solution.

I also looked at trying to communicate with "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/", but, even with it added to the content_security_policy, I am unable to query for JSON.

Just curious if anyone has a solution I'm not seeing / has tackled this issue

I used RobW's answer in jQuery:

```
$.get('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp', function(result){
    var geoplugin = JSON.parse(result.replace(/^[^\{]+/, '').replace(/\);?$/, ''));
    console.log(geoplugin.geoplugin_countryCode);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Chrome extension, you can do cross-origin requests when the URL is whitelisted at the manifest file, at the `"permissions"` section.

Output of http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp (note: `json` instead of `javascript`):

```
geoPlugin({
  "geoplugin_request":"x.x.x.x",
  "geoplugin_status":200,
  "geoplugin_city":"...",
  ...
})
```

This output format is not JSON, but JSONP. The function call is not relevant. So strip the padding (`geoPlugin(` and `)`) before parsing:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
    var json = xhr.responseText.replace(/^[^\{]+/, '').replace(/\);?$/, '');
    json = JSON.parse(json);
    // Example, alert latitude and longitude
    alert(json.geoplugin_latitude + ', ' + json.geoplugin_longitude);
};
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp');
xhr.send();
```

[Manifest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html) file:

```
  ...
  "permissions": ["http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp"],
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I learned a lot. I had no idea that I could interface with non-https websites, at all!